# Trying to get the indices of an element from a list in scheme

Tags: list, function, helper, indices

So i'm trying to get the indices from a list ex:

(get-indices 'G (list 'A 'G 'T 'X 'I 'T 'G))

(2 7)

where the index starts at 1 so 'A is index one

I was thinking on using a helper function where it takes an elt lst and index 
ex: (get-indices-helper el lst index)

I was also thinking about possibly using list-ref and like switching it to make it work in the get indices way however i could not find the actual scheme definition for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a function that recurses down the input list, keeping track of the position of the element that it's looking at, and emitting the matching indexes with `cons`. This is really trivial; I assume that it is a question that you have been set as homework?

```
; Walk down the list given in haystack, returning a list of indices at which
; values equal? to needle appear.
(define (get-indices needle haystack)
  ; Loop along the haystack.
  (define (loop rest-of-haystack index)
    ; If the haystack is empty, return the empty list.
    (if (null? rest-of-haystack) '()
      ; Recurse to the next position in the list.
      (let ((rest-of-indices (loop (cdr rest-of-haystack) (+ index 1))))
        (if (equal? (car rest-of-haystack) needle)
          ; If haystack is here, emit the current index.
          (cons index rest-of-indices)
          ; Otherwise, return rest-of-indices.
          rest-of-indices))))
  ; Run the loop defined above, from the beginning of haystack, with
  ; the first element being assigned an index of 1.
  (loop haystack 1))
```

Testing this with GNU Guile or MzScheme or something:

```
(display (get-indices 'G (list 'A 'G 'T 'X 'I 'T 'G))) (newline)
(display (get-indices 1 (list 1 1 1 2 1 3))) (newline)
```

Prints:

```
(2 7)
(1 2 3 5)
```

Yay!